# Executing array of child objects methods in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Suppose I have a base class A and two derived classes B and C. I want to create an array of function pointers that consist of virtual members of both B and C and execute them.

How do I do this?

I really want to go one further and not even have the objects share a parent class but I figured this was easier.

Comment: Sounds like what you want is polymorphism.  You'll have an array of pointer to the base class that themselves point to derived objects and then use virtual functions to "do the right thing".

Comment: Could you give example? I don't understand how this would work.

Comment: Your C++ book should have a section on polymorphism.

Comment: I don't understand how you can cast the base class pointers to the derived classes, this isn't talked about in standard exples.

Comment: You _don't_ cast the base class pointer. That's what polymorphism provides. The virtual function table automatically maps to the correct override for the underlying object.

Answer (score 1):

If you have
`class A { virtual void f() = 0; };`

And classes B and C derived from A, then you can do

```
using memfuncptr = void(A::*)();
memfuncptr memfuncs[] {&B::f};
A a;
a.*(memfuncs[0]);
```

This does require that all member functions desired be members of A.

Comment: Consider updating your example to valid code that compiles without errors. There are multiple problems with it.

Comment: I included the syntax of pointer-to-member-functions. The definition of the classes it if to the OP. IF classes B and C are defined, and include f(), the code should compile. Unfortunately, I am on mobile and a full answer is impractical.